Setting custom primary key with NgRx signal store withEntities
Problem
I have an ngrx/signalStore that contains fruits as entities. For proper usage of the signalStore, you need to have an id field in the Fruit class, but the API I use retrieves fruits that have a field  fruitId. Is there a way to tell the store that it will be the primary key for the class instead of introducing a duplicated field named id?
Here is my store:
export const FruitStore = signalStore(
  { providedIn: 'root' },
  withEntities<Fruit>(),
  withMethods((
    store,
    fruitService = inject(FruitService),
  ) => ({
    loadFruits: rxMethod<void>(
      pipe(
        exhaustMap(() => {
          return fruitService.getFruits().pipe(
            tapResponse({
              next: (fruits) => {
                patchState(store, setAllEntities(fruits);
              },
              error: (error: { message: string }) => {
                console.log(error.message);
              }
            }),
          );
        }),
      )
    ),
  })),
  withHooks({
    onInit({ loadFruits }) {
      loadFruits();
    }
  }),
);

My Fruit class:
export class Fruit {
  fruitId: number;
  name: string;
  imageURL: string;
}

Current solution
My current solution is to add a duplicated field to the class (Fruit class comes from the API generated with OpenAPI, so I can not change it). But I'm not fully satisfied with this solution. Do you have any ideas to improve it?
export type WithId<T> = T & { id: number };

Changes in the store:
export const FruitStore = signalStore(
  { providedIn: 'root' },
  // Extend Fruit class 'WithId'
  withEntities<WithId<Fruit>>(),
  withMethods((
    store,
    fruitService = inject(FruitService),
  ) => ({
    loadFruits: rxMethod<void>(
      pipe(
        exhaustMap(() => {
          return fruitService.getFruits().pipe(
            tapResponse({
              next: (fruits) => {
                // Add the duplicated field
                patchState(store, setAllEntities(fruits.map(fruit => ({ ...fruit, id: fruit.fruitId })));
              },
              error: (error: { message: string }) => {
                console.log(error.message);
              }
            }),
          );
        }),
      )
    ),
  })),
  withHooks({
    onInit({ loadFruits }) {
      loadFruits();
    }
  }),
);


I couldn't create a new ngrx-signal-store tag, but I think that should be the most relevant one for the problem.

When working with angular 17, you need to specify the idKey property in the second argument object of setAllEntities.
  ...
  withMethods((store) => {
    const todoService = inject(TodoService);
    return {
      loadTodos: rxMethod<void>(
        pipe(
          exhaustMap(() => {
            return todoService.getTodos().pipe(
              tap((fruits) => {
                // Add the duplicated field
                patchState(
                  store,
                  setAllEntities<Todo>(
                    fruits.map((fruit) => ({ ...fruit })),
                    { idKey: 'todoId' }
                  )
                );
              })
            );
          })
        )
      ),
      ...

Stackblitz Demo -> 4th tab in the application.

When you are working with latest version of angular (17+). The process is present in the documentation.
NGRX Docs - Custom Entity Identifier
import { patchState, signalStore, withMethods } from '@ngrx/signals';
import {
  addEntities,
  removeEntity,
  SelectEntityId,
  setEntity,
  updateAllEntities,
  withEntities,
} from '@ngrx/signals/entities';

type Todo = {
  key: number;
  text: string;
  completed: boolean;
};

const selectId: SelectEntityId<Todo> = (todo) => todo.key;

export const TodosStore = signalStore(
  withEntities<Todo>(),
  withMethods((store) => ({
    addTodos(todos: Todo[]): void {
      patchState(store, addEntities(todos, { selectId }));
    },
    setTodo(todo: Todo): void {
      patchState(store, setEntity(todo, { selectId }));
    },
    completeAllTodos(): void {
      patchState(
        store,
        updateAllEntities({ completed: true }, { selectId })
      );
    },
    removeTodo(key: number): void {
      patchState(store, removeEntity(key));
    },
  }))
);


Thanks for the quick reply! It's a very nice solution.
